# how to read 1 excel file with multiple sheet

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I need to get specific value from data table 1 sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, sheet4 and write it to specific cell in my data table 2.

what approach I should do.
I want it to be dynamic.

Comment: Hi Leo, please add more info what "dynamic" means. If possible add the example process with all the activities and excel files.

Answer (score 0):

Please do provide more specific. I am assuming you need to read all the sheets in an excel file and act to that data. For read all the sheets in an Excel file (.xlsx) I used the following:

[image: Excel Scope activity and Get Workbook Sheets activity]

Then I iterated through the sheet names to read each sheet
[image: Iterate sheetnames]

Hope this helps for the first part of your question!